# How to check if event overlaps other events on update?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, events, sql-update

I have created events. I want to check if the events overlaps. For this I have a function in database to check if events overlaps. I have saved dates for this, from date and to date.

But for update, if I want to extend the time of my event , it shows event exists. How can I update event by checking if current event is not overlapping another event?

function:

```
  boolean doesEventOverlap(String startTime, String endTime, String day) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = '" + day + "'" + " AND "

            + "(" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + endTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " ('" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_FROM_DATE
            + " AND " + KEY_TO_DATE + " < '" + endTime + "')";


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            EventData event = new EventData();
            return cursor.getInt(0) > 0;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return false;
}
```

create table:

```
public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FROM_DATE + " DATE,"
            + KEY_TO_DATE + " DATE,"
            + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + " DATE,"
            + KEY_COLOR + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: could I see the createtable statement

Comment: please check edited question. @Mark Gilchrist

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the code I would use and the changes I suggest for you

1) refactor your code to use the Keyword Between $value AND $Value

2) unless I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve you only need to see if the start-time is between any event or the end time.

3) I have changed the select statement so that you get a reference to all the ids of overlapping events. (you statement doesn't need a do while loop as a Select count statement only ever has one row!)

4) add a ; to the end of the statement for security reasons

```
boolean doesEventOverlap(String startTime, String endTime, String day) {
String selectQuery = "SELECT "+ KEY_ID +" FROM " + TABLE + 
" WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = '" + day + "'" +
" AND "
+ "('" + startTime + "'  BETWEEN "+ KEY_FROM_DATE + " AND " +KEY_TO_DATE+")
OR
('" + endTime + "'  BETWEEN "+ KEY_FROM_DATE + " AND " +KEY_TO_DATE+");";


  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        EventData event = new EventData();

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    return cursor.getCount() > 0;
  }
return false
}
```

as for updating the time of your current Event I would run this function to see if it overlaps, then if it returns false I would find the next start point from the database greater than your current event with the below sql

```
"SELECT '"+ KEY_FROM_DATE + "' FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE '"+ KEY_FROM_DATE + "'> "+endtime+";"
```

if you then the value you get from your cursor - your end time - 1 second is the amount you can extend the event by. I hope this helps